# using lambda in find in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a method that does a paginated find call like..

## 1

```
coll = paginate(:all, lambda {{:conditions => ['status = ? AND expires < ?', 'a', DateTime.now]}}, :select => Constants::POST_FIELDS,
                   :order => 'posts.ratings DESC', :include => [{:poster => :poster_friends}, :category], :per_page => Constants::LISTINGS_PER_PAGE,
                   :page => page)
```

When this call runs it simply ignores the conditions in the generated query.

## 2

If I try it in a named_scope I get an error like..

```
named_scope :featured_all, lambda {{:conditions => ['status = ? AND expires < ?', 'a', DateTime.now], order => 'posts.ratings DESC', :include => [{:poster => :poster_friends},  :category],
            :select => Constants::POST_FIELDS}}
```

The named-scope error :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:47:in `assert_valid_keys'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2101:in `with_scope'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:113:in `__send__'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:113:in `with_scope'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:174:in `method_missing'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:188:in `load_found'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:166:in `proxy_found'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:109:in `is_a?'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hirb-0.3.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:78:in `determine_output_class'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hirb-0.3.1/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:48:in `format_output'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hirb-0.3.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:213:in `render_output'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hirb-0.3.1/lib/hirb/view.rb:126:in `view_output'
```

For #1. What am I doing wrong, why is it ignoring the conditions?

For #2 Why this error? And also, how can I pass the :page and per_page parameter to limit the query in the named_scope.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you wrapping the conditions in a lambda?

Comment: So that I get the correct DateTime.now. If I don't, won't that call just return the DateTime.now, since the server was started?

Comment: @badnaam: The only difference wrapping it in a lambda and then immediately calling it would make is that time returned would be a few microseconds slower to account for the time taken by the lambda call itself.

Comment: So, it is OK to take the lambda off? It would still return the correct/current time in the conditions, not the time when the model was loaded?

Comment: Chuck's incorrect; it would be a couple seconds behind in development, where model classes are reloaded per-request, but it would get "stuck" in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case does not warrant a named_scope. You can write a regular finder as follows:

```
coll = paginate(:select     => Constants::POST_FIELDS,
                :conditions => ['status = ? AND expires < ?', 'a', DateTime.now],
                :include    => [{:poster => :poster_friends}, :category],
                :order      => 'posts.ratings DESC',  
                :per_page   => Constants::LISTINGS_PER_PAGE,
                :page => page)
```

The `paginate` method is equivalent to `all`, so you don't have to supply the `:all` result-set scope qualifier to the `paginate` method.

The time value is calculated upon the execution of the query. This is unlike a named_scope, where you have to use a lambda for the same effect.

If you need to use the named_scope then do the following:

```
named_scope :featured_all, lambda {{
                :select     => Constants::POST_FIELDS,
                :conditions => ['status = ? AND expires < ?', 'a', DateTime.now],
                :include    => [{:poster => :poster_friends}, :category],
                :order      => 'posts.ratings DESC'
               }}
```

Now you can use the named_scope as follows

```
Post.feature_all.paginate(:per_page => Constants::LISTINGS_PER_PAGE, 
                          :page => page)
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know the time value is calculated upon query execution! The finder works just fine. The named scope crashed with an sql error message complaining about invlid attribute categories.id, I guess there is some sort of confusion in named scope if the :select clause contains an assocation.id or any other column with the same name? I have :select => 'posts.id, categories.id'

Comment: You have to use an alias (e.g.: `categories.id AS categories_id` ) while referring to joined tables in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your named scope is missing a `:` before your order key. That might be blowing up the named scope. Otherwise, it looks fine.

That said, you don't need to use a lambda to get records relevant to the current time. Your database provides methods that do similar. For example, if you are using MySQL, you can use:

```
named_scope(:featured_all, {
  :conditions => "status = 'a' AND expires < UTC_TIMESTAMP()",
  :order => 'posts.ratings DESC',
  :include => [{:poster => :poster_friends}, :category],
  :select => Constants::POST_FIELDS
})
```

`UTC_TIMESTAMP()` is a MySQL-specific function that returns the current date and time in UTC (which Rails should be storing your DateTimes as already).

Comment: I would rather not use a db specific code here. Any other option or am I fine without the lambda? You are right about the :order. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to avoid DB-specific code, you'll need to use the lambda. It'll work without the lambda in development, but it'll get stuck in production, where model classes aren't reloaded per-request.