# Can I paginate results by year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I have a collection about 100 objects per year over 25 years. It would be nice to list them by year, per page, so that it would be easier to drill down to a particular object. Is there a plugin or gem for paginating Rails collections by year, instead of a fixed number of items? Maybe even by month? Would it be possible to adapt will_paginate to do this?

EDIT:

`ss = Services.all.group_by { |s| s.date_of_service.year }`

This produces an ordered hash over which I can paginate by keys.

`ss.keys.each { |k| p ss[k].count }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find such gem. And it shouldn't be that hard to implement a simple pagination system yourself using scopes.

I suppose you don't have a separate table for years. So to retrieve the full list of unique years, you should use `group` method.

```
  scope :years, lambda { select('year').group('year') }
  scope :year, lambda { |year| where(:year => year) }
```

The other option would be what keruilin suggested. Use any pagination gem (I use kaminari) with the `year` scope.

Comment: I'm on Rails 2.x. I can use `named_scope :year, lambda { |y| { :conditions => "YEAR(date_of_service) = #{y}" } }` for the second part, but this is all I can come up with on the first. Surely there's a better way.`def self.years; ys = []; Service.all.collect { |s| ys << s.date_of_service.year }; ys.uniq!; end`

Comment: I have no experience with rails2, but I think it should be possible to use `lambda { find(:select => 'year', :group => 'year') }`

Comment: Cool. I didn't know `:select` was available in Rails 2. Your method gets me a list of objects with a single attribute. I thought it would just return the attribute. I think I want the list of years my class method gives me. Anyway, I have just found this; maybe I can get some mileage from it as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488534/using-lambda-in-find-in-rails

Comment: Oh, you're right. I guess you can get an array of attributes using the `map!` method: `lambda { select('year').group('year').map!{ |obj| obj.year| }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement general pagination using will_paginate.  You'll have, for ex, 10-25 results per page no matter what year that you're viewing.

I'd then implement a second filtering mechanism by which you view results by year using some good ole AR / SQL magic.  With my app, I used a drop-down to select the year, but you can user some other UI element.

I can't say for sure if will_paginate can help you with the by-year issue, but I wouldn't advise customizing it to fit your needs.  Just creates a compatibility issue unless you monkeypatch.